# Jquery-ui open dialog from php loop

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

there are probably many ways to achieve want I want to do but I just need the easiest way.
I using a php for loop to display data from db.
I wanna show dialog from database that changes values to match the php for loop values. Now it only shows last rows values from database.

The  $(this).parent().submit(); is there because I copied it from another working solution :)

Here's what I've tried but to dialog just shows the last row and the id is not changing.
PHP:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $numrows ; $i++){
echo ('<div style="float: left; min-height: 20px; font-size: 14px; width: 266px;
padding-left: 5px;" class="emailTopicStyle"><a class="show" name="id" value="'.$id.'" href="#">'.$topic.'</a></div>');

echo ('<div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; 
font-size: 14px; min-height: 20px;" class="emailTopicStyle">'.$body.'</div>');

 }

}
echo ('<div id="dialog-open" title="Sent, '.$sent.'">');
echo ('<p style="line-height: 1.2em; font-weight: bold; padding-bottom: 8px;"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-mail-closed" style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 20px 0; "></span>Aihe: '.$topic.'</p>');
echo ('<p style="line-height: 1.2em;"><span style="float: left;"></span>Body: '.$body.'</p>');
echo ('</div>'); 
echo ('<div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>').PHP_EOL;
```

Jquery:

```
var formvalue ='';
    $( "#dialog-open" ).dialog({
      resizable: true,
      height:300,
      width: 600,
      modal: true,
      autoOpen: false,
      buttons: {
        "Sulje": function() {
            $('[name=id]').each(function() {
            if (formvalue == $(this).val()) {
                $(this).parent().submit();
            }
            });
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );        
        }
      }
    });


 $( ".show" ).click(function() {
 formvalue = $(this).parent().find('[name=id]').val();
 $( "#dialog-open" ).dialog( "open" );
})
```

Resulting html:

```
This is testsubject Testaillaan numero 1.. 30.03.2014 09:30:20 2868
This is testsubject Testaillaan numero 2.. 30.03.2014 09:30:33 2869
This is testsubject Ja lisää testiä.. 30.03.2014 14:31:31 2870
```

as html:

```
<div style="float: left; min-height: 20px; font-size: 14px; width: 266px; padding-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;" class="emailTopicStyle"><a class="show" name="id" value="2" href="#">Tämä on testiotsikko</a></div><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 14px; min-height: 20px;" class="emailTopicStyle">Testaillaan numero 1..</div><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 14px; min-height: 20px;" class="emailTopicStyle">30.03.2014 09:30:20</div><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 10px; font-size: 14px; min-height: 20px;" 

class="emailTopicStyle">2868</div>
<div style="float: left; min-height: 20px; font-size: 14px; width: 266px; padding-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;" class="emailTopicStyle"><a class="show" name="id" value="3" href="#">Tämä on testiotsikko</a></div><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 14px; min-height: 20px;" class="emailTopicStyle">Testaillaan numero 2..</div><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 14px; min-height: 20px;" class="emailTopicStyle">30.03.2014 09:30:33</div><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 10px; font-size: 14px; min-height: 20px;" class="emailTopicStyle">2869</div>

</div><div style="float: left; min-height: 20px; font-size: 14px; width: 266px; padding-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 2px;" class="emailTopicStyle"><a class="show" name="id" value="4" href="#">Tämä on testiotsikko</a></div><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 14px; min-height: 20px;" class="emailTopicStyle">Ja lisää testiä..</div><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 14px; min-height: 20px;" class="emailTopicStyle">30.03.2014 14:31:31</div><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 10px; font-size: 14px; min-height: 20px;" class="emailTopicStyle">2870</div>
```

Br,
Toube

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. What must be in the modal? The "$body" part matching the "a" tag clicked?

Comment: Hi, sry forgot.. I edited the php code in the question.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand ... The PHP part is incomplete anyway. Maybe you should paste the resulting html and could explain what you want in the dialog box.

Comment: Hi, I pasted the resulting html. So now when I click any of those links the dialog will always show the last one with the 2780 id from the database.. when instead of course the dialog should open the row / id theat has been clicked.

Comment: Hmm .. This is not HTML this is pure text.

Comment: printed html output from source, so when if I click on any of those links it will always open the last one in the dialog with id value="4". I I click the link with id value="2" opens the the id value="4".. got it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change line

```
formvalue = $(this).parent().find('[name=id]').val();
```

into

```
formvalue = $(this).parent().find('[name=id]').attr('value');
```

**Edit:**

I've made a fiddle with what I think you are expecting. You can inspire from it to do what you want to do : http://jsfiddle.net/cYEsp/2/

Comment: Thanks, ok that will give a value of the last row in the query: alert (formvalue); But still same issue..

Comment: Well I definitively don't understand what you want. I think it would be helpful if you paste HTML and JS to http://jsfiddle.net